# why we can not have a function in a function in c?

Tags: c, function

Why we cannot have functions like

```
int fun1( )
  {
       \\ statements;
        int fun2( )
            {
                \\ here we are defining a function in another function

            }
 }
```

So my question is that why the defination of fun2 is illegal?

Comment: Because the standard doesn't allow that.

Comment: I would ask u a question : and what is the difference if you would define the fun2 legally and just call it  from within fun1 ?

Comment: @Roma-MT: Namespace collision stuff maybe.But as devnull said, it just isn´t allowed

Comment: Roma-MT there's a difference, you are polluting the namespace

Comment: @zmo IMO *that* question doesn't ask for the *reason* why it's not allowed.

Comment: @LuisAlves what do u mean ? it is C

Comment: @dyp it shows there are exceptions to the rule ;-)

Comment: I mean that by declaring a function legally (outside of fun2) you are not allowing to declare another function with the same name. (Of course that in C you you can't do nothing against this)

Comment: @LuisAlves you mean if it would be allowed , that only fun1 could use it ?
but still what is it good for , if C is not even OOP

Comment: (GCC extension forgive it) is not a special issue of the implementation language. Just not allowed in C.